# How to create an inline validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Is there a way to create inline validations in Rails? For example convert this

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  validate :active_customer

  def active_customer
    errors.add(:customer_id, "is not active") unless customer.active?
  end
end
```

to something like this

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  validate { errors.add(:customer_id, "is not active") unless customer.active? }
end
```

Comment: Your example seems fine to me, are you getting a specific error?
I'm comparing to this example from the rails guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-add

Comment: This should work fine, you might have to add a check for `customer` if the customer object is present or not so it doesn't throw an exception.